# change the style of all input-fields that contain only a "1"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use a style on my website, that has one deficit: the number "1" looks exactly like a big "I" and like a small "L".

How can I dynamically change with javascript the font-style for all input-fields that contain as value only the number "1" without having to change all forms on that site?

(I use jquery on that site a lot anyway)

Or maybe with CSS3?

Comment: Do you intend for the style to change back and forth as the value is being changed?

Comment: Use $('input:text').css('font-family','<font_u_need>'); It will work.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: that would be perfect!

Comment: Added a version which changes back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote my comment "Do you intend for the style to change back and forth as the value is being changed" as a rhetorical question to illustrate the clunkiness of such an approach, but if that's really what you want, sure.

First of all, you need to make sure that the style is set once at DOMReady and once every time an input is changed.

```
$(function() { 
    $(':text')
        .each(setInputStyle)
        .change(setInputStyle);
});
```

Then you need to make sure `setInputStyle` checks for what you want to check. I'm not sure if you're looking to change all inputs that *contain* `1` or only the inputs that *are exactly* 1. You would use one of the following checks:

- Contains:

  ```
  var inputValue1 = this.value.indexOf('1') >= 0;
  ```
- Matches exactly

  ```
  var inputValue1 = this.value == '1';
  ```
- or perhaps, "Contains only ones":

  ```
  var inputValue1 = /^1+$/.test(this.value);
  ```

Regardless of what you look for, you'd incorporate it in your function like so:

```
function setInputStyle() {
    var inputValue1 = this.value == '1'; // or something else
    $(this).toggleClass('input-value-1', inputValue1);
}
```

Now you'd only need to make sure that there's a CSS class called `input-value-1` that overrides the default styles.

```
.input-value-1 { font-family: verdana; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KWh4V/)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the font family used for all input boxes. You don't want it to differ between fields, that would look odd

Comment: there are far too many, the site is really big. and most of them need that style!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $.each($('input'),function(){
    if($(this).val() == '1'){
     $(this).css('color','red');
    }
    });
    });
```

or

```
$('input[value="1"]').css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correct, you want a different font everytime a 1 is contained by the value of the input field.

This would work for value "1" and also for "abc de 1 fg"

**JS**

```
$('input[value*="1"]').css({'font-family':'Helvetica','color':'#990000'});
```

Check it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/U3weP/1/

To have it specific to the value 1, just remove the * in the selector.

**JS**

```
$('input[value="1"]').css({'font-family':'Helvetica','color':'#990000'});
```

To make it change while typing you can use the following function, it will also change back to its normal state.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="test1" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="test2" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="test3" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="test4" value="abc 1 def" />
```

**CSS**

```
.different {
    font-family:'Helvetica';
    color:#990000;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('input').on('keyup',function() {
    if($(this).val().indexOf('1') != -1) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('different')) {
            $(this).addClass('different');
        }
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('different');
    }
}).trigger('keyup');
```

View on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3weP/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try the value filter:

```
$('input[value=1]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input:text [value="1"]').css('font-family','Arial')
```

Answer (score 0):

With following code attached at page bottom you will be able to change style of all existing inputs and watch them for any changes. If the `1` will appear in any input `someclass` will be added to that element. If `1` will be remove so will the class.

```
function onCharacter1Found() {
  var field = $(this),
      classname = "someclass",
      containsChar_1 = field.val().indexOf(1) > 1;
  if(containsChar_1) { 
    field.addClass(classname);
  } else {
    field.removeClass(classname);
  }
};

// update all existing inputs on the page
$("input").each(onCharacter1Found);

// watch for changes
$("input").bind("input", onCharacter1Found);
```